In the USA, do citizens have the right to an absentee balot?
In the US, do you have the right to mail your vote during election time?

States have implemented two options: vote-by-mail and in-person early voting in a ~2-4 week window. Some states call the latter "in-person absentee voting" because they run under the same statutes. I think you're asking solely for vote-by-mail.

Allowing voting by mail for Federal offices is required for certain groups of citizens (uniformed service members, merchant marine, their family members, and overseas citizens) by the Uniformed And Overseas Citizens Absentee Voting Act. For others, it's a matter for the state to decide.
For 2024:
3 states require a qualifying reason to vote by mail, otherwise you must vote in person on election day: Alabama, Mississippi, New Hampshire
11 states require a qualifying reason to vote by mail but offer in-person early voting to all: Arkansas, Connecticut, Delaware, Indiana, Kentucky, Louisiana, Missouri, Tennessee, Texas, South Carolina, West Virginia
8 states plus DC default to voting by mail, though all offer a form of in-person early voting: California, Colorado, District of Columbia, Hawaii, Nevada, Oregon, Utah, Vermont, Washington
The remaining 28 states offer vote by mail on request without an excuse
47 states and DC offer in-person early voting: all but the three above
Sources: National Conference of State Legislatures, CBS News

While it is required for certain groups those are small in number and there are a lot more that don't qualify for that. Also just because they say you can vote early doesn't mean they actually make it easy to do so.

Connecticut will be voting next week on whether to amend its constitution to allow no-excuse absentee voting. So this answer may need to change soon.

@MichaelSeifert While that is true that won't impact this election which is what the answer is focusing on.

Also, in Presidential elections only, for people who have relocated to a new state and don't meet the residency requirements of the new state yet, even if an absentee ballot wouldn't otherwise be allowed under state law.

In certain circumstances
australia

You can apply for a postal vote if on election day you:

are outside the division where you are enrolled to vote

are more than 8km from a polling place

are travelling

are unable to leave your workplace to vote

are seriously ill, infirm, or due to give birth shortly (or caring for someone who is)

are a patient in hospital and can't vote at the hospital

have religious beliefs that prevent you from attending a polling place

are in prison serving a sentence of less than three years or otherwise detained

are a silent elector

have a reasonable fear for your safety.



On these same basis, you can pre-poll instead.
From experience, these reasons are not heavily interrogated. Basically you get asked two questions:

Is there a reason you cannot vote on election day?
Have you already voted in this election?

If the answers are respectively yes and no, you get your postal or pre-poll vote.

Likewise in Spain; absentee ballots are available but it must be justified by some specific reason (I do not know the complete list). I guess this is to get as many people as possible to vote in person, in an environment where coercion and control would be more difficult. Also, someone who has sent an absentee ballot can go to the voting poll and vote; mail votes are added last and if someone appears to have been voted in person, his envelope is just discarded and (guess) destroyed.

It depends on which state you live in as there are different requirements for each state. Some offer it only with an excuse that they consider valid. One thing to note is that while most states offer early voting that is not the same as absentee voting as it still requires you to be present in person.
Map shows which states offer early voting and mail-in ballots for the 2024 election

States that offer early voting for all but require an eligible reason
for mail-in ballots
Here are the states that have early in-person
voting but require an eligible reason to vote by mail.
Connecticut
Indiana
Kentucky
Louisiana
Missouri
South Carolina
Tennessee
Texas
West Virginia
States where no early voting option is
available to all voters, and an eligible reason to vote by mail is
needed
Three states do not offer early voting and require an eligible
reason to vote by mail, which means not everyone in these states has
an option to vote on any day but Election Day.
Alabama
Mississippi
New Hampshire

Note that early voting is not the same as absentee voting as you still have to vote in person. One of the main reasons for absentee voting is because the person is unable to vote in person. There is also a limited amount of time to early vote. As an example in Texas early voting is from 17 to 4 days before the elections with the dates being adjusted for the weekend. For this election that is October 21st to November 1st.
Early Voting

Generally, early voting in person begins the 17th day before Election
Day (if that’s a weekend, early voting starts on Monday) and ends the
4th day before Election Day. Vote at a location in your political
subdivision that’s close to where you live or work. All other voting
rules and procedures apply – e.g., eligibility and polling hours.


No, your numbers are from the COVID era. This article shows a different situation for 2024.

@user71659 It seems that they just undercount the number of states that don't give the right to an absentee ballot, I will update it with more current numbers later today. The answer is still valid overall as it shows that it is not a right in every part of the country.
